# Oracle ADF: richButton.setDisabled(true) not working in 12c

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hello I am using jdeveloper 12c. I have a test.jsf page in that I have form with a button. In the backing bean of this page I have actionListener method addKPI(ActionEvent e). when user click this button it calls addKPI() method. In this method I am doing some operations and after that I am trying to disable it using `richButton.setDisable(true)`. It is not working in 12c. It is working in jdeveloper 11.1.2.4.

Please help me. How do I achieve this. My requirement is when user click this button I need to disable it. Means the button should be clickable only once.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try firing a programatic PPR from the action listener:

```
public void addKPI(ActionEvent e) {
  .........
  richButton.setDisable(true);
  AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(richButton);

}
```

Comment: Wonderful Marcus. It is perfectly working. Thanks a lot. Thank you very much.